# Landing Page in UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I want to create a Landing Page with XAML for my UWP App but I dont know how. :/ I know how to load pages within the Content Frame of my Main Program, but when I click on the button on my Main Page and I want it to load the ProgramFrame, it says in the .cs code "MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));" Main Frame is not available. Also, is it possible to determine if an app is being started the first time and only shows the landing page then?

Thanks!

- [MainPage.xaml.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Y9j.png)  & [LandingPage.xaml.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AARmo.png)

Comment: Can you try using `Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));` ?

Comment: yes, worked for me!